# Is there any way to automatically change the instance type of an aws ec2 instance without any downtime?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I want to change the instance type of an aws ec2 instance based on the cpu utilization of the instance. Basically i want the instance type to be t3.large if the cpu utilization is > 80% and t3.medium if it is below that. Is there any way to achieve this without any downtime? Can i achieve this with aws cloudformation? If so can you provide me a guide or link which i can refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do this. Changing instance type [requires](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html) stopping your instance:

> You **must stop** your Amazon EBS–backed instance before you can change its instance type.

However, you could  setup your instance(s) to operate in an **autoscaling group**. This way you could use [UpdatePolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatepolicy.html) to perform rolling or replacing update. This could be use to ensure that  part or full  fleet of your instances is operating while the new instance types are rolled out.